# Substring from different parts of a string

Tags: c#

I have a string which contains white characters and I want to substring some values from it.

```
string mystring = "1. JoshTestLowdop 192";
 (from 1. to J there's a whitespace)
string FirstNO = mystring.Substring(0, mystring.IndexOf(' '));
string Name = mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf(' '), mystring.LastIndexOf(' '));
string ID = mystring.Substring(mystring.LastIndexOf(' ');
```

But unfortunately the string Name also contains the number 1 from the 192 ..which shouldn't.

Can someone explain ..what's wrong?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: The expected output should be : firstNO = "1." , Name = "JoshTestLowdop" and ID = "192"

Answer (score 2):

The second argument to `Substring` is a "length" parameter, not the position in the string. You need to subtract the start position.

Also not that your current version contains the whitespace after "1.", so Name is actually " JoshTestLowdop". You need to add 1 to the first substring to get the actual name.

```
string mystring = "1. JoshTestLowdop 192";
int start = mystring.IndexOf(' ');
string FirstNO = mystring.Substring(0, start);
string Name = mystring.Substring(start + 1, mystring.LastIndexOf(' ') - (start + 1));
string ID = mystring.Substring(mystring.LastIndexOf(' ') + 1);
Console.WriteLine(FirstNO);
Console.WriteLine(Name);
Console.WriteLine(ID);

// outputs:
1.
JoshTestLowdop
192
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) method :

```
string mystring = "1. JoshTestLowdop 192";

var splitted = mystring.Split(new(){' '});

string FirstNo = splitted[0];
string name = splitted[1];
string ID = splitted[2];
```

This is assuming that the names don't contain white spaces as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your second parameter to Substring function. It should be:

```
string Name = mystring.Substring(mystring.IndexOf(' '), mystring.LastIndexOf(' ')-mystring.IndexOf(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
string mystring = "1. JoshTestLowdop 192";    

string[] strs = mystring.Split(' ');

string FirstNO =strs[0];
string Name = strs[1];
string ID = strs[2];
```